# Why the size of Flutter app is too big during development

Tags: flutter, dart

I see my app size during development is about 500 MB. Is this the normal size of the Flutter app during development? Why is it this big?

Comment: it's ok, to have big package during development, since many dependencies have their nested dependencies. example in my app big folders are: android, ios, build

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Apps are supposed to be bigger in Debug mode as it loads several components needed for Hot Reload and Hot Restart, plus all the communications with the development tools. Once you compile your App to Release it will get smaller.

That being said, 500MB is A LOT and it shouldn't be related to the Flutter Framework, but probably to any Assets you added to your project.

Comment: if 500 MB is a lot, what is the size of a basic app should be? Note that I am using material package in flutter.

Comment: I don't know from memory, just create a new project and check. But I think either you are filling your app with resources or maybe you are measuring something else that's not the APK.